# What is (-π)! demonstration?

Tags: factorial

## (-π)!

Maybe

```
  (-π)! = (-3.1415926535897932384626433832795)! = -3.1909066873083528993320905932927
```

if this result is correct then

```
 What is the demonstration?
```

Comment: No demonstration

Answer (score 5):

The factorial is usually  considered to be defined only for  natural numbers. One standard way to extend the definition of factorial outside this set is to consider the gamma function: $\Gamma (x+1) = x! $ when $x $ is a natural numbers but is also defined, for example, when $x=-\pi $. In fact, $\Gamma(-\pi+1)\simeq -3.19$. With a slight abuse of notation whoever our whatever told you that  $(-\pi)!\simeq -3.19$ most likely adopted the extended definition provided by the gamma function.

Comment: Demonstration ?

Comment: @FelinoAudi you will find all you need in the (Wiki article on the Gamma function) [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function]

Comment: @FelinoAudi ... and also at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Extension_of_factorial_to_non-integer_values_of_argument

Comment: Well this graphic helps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#/media/File:Generalized_factorial_function.svg

Answer (score 1):

It's nonsensical.

But often, factorial notation is used to mean the [gamma function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(-pi)!) rather than factorials: specifically, $n!$ is used to mean $\Gamma(n+1)$

Comment: Note that $\Gamma(1-\pi)$ is roughly the RHS written down by the OP...

Answer (score 0):

The factorial function is generally understood to be defined only for the domain $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$. However, it coincides with another function, the gamma function, which is defined for all real numbers except for non-positive integers. In particular, $n!=\Gamma(n+1)$. Thus, we could identify $(-\pi)!$ as $\Gamma(-\pi+1)$.

The value of this function would be the number you wrote down.